# Second symbol on arrows in the package mhchem

Tags: mhchem

Why does the following formula have problem?

```
$\ce{A ->[k''] B}$
```

It doesn't have any problem with prime symbol but with second symbol it won't be compiled.

Any idea about how to use second symbol in this package?

Comment: Try `$\ce{A ->[{k''}] B}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping the argument seems to solve the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
$\ce{A ->[{k''}] B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needed the `k` in math mode, then `$\ce{A ->[{$k''$}] B}$` would do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
$\ce{A ->[{$k''$}] B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the k must be in math mode. I am willing to bet that it represent a velocity constant…